# How to delete multiple gridview items at once

Tags: java, android, gridview, delete-file, image-gallery

I created an image gallery app which displays images as a **gridview**. I can select multiple photos at a time but I am not able to delete all of them at once by clicking the delete button. *I am not using checkboxes because it doesn't go well with the design of my app.* I tried finding a way but almost all of them use checkboxes.Can anyone suggest me how to delete multiple photos at once without using checkboxes?

**PhotosActivity.java**:

```
public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int int_position;
    private GridView gridView;
    GridViewAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Object> mSelected = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean boolean_folder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);

        final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final ImageButton button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        final ImageButton button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        final ImageButton button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        button1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        int_position = getIntent().getIntExtra("value", 0);
        adapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, al_images, int_position);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String abc = "file://" + al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position);

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                i.putExtra("folderPosition", int_position);
                i.putExtra("abc", abc);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                String position1 = new String(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position));
                if(mSelected.contains(position1)) {
                    mSelected.remove(position1);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);// remove item from list
                    // update view (v) state here
                    // eg: remove highlight
                }
                else {
                    mSelected.add(position1);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);// add item to list
                    // update view (v) state here
                    // eg: add highlight
                }


                button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotosActivity.this);
                                builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete it ?");
                                builder1.setCancelable(true);

                                builder1.setPositiveButton(
                                        "Yes",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                deleteSelectedItems();
                                                al_images.remove(position);
                                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        });

                                builder1.setNegativeButton(
                                        "No",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                dialog.cancel();
                                            }
                                        });

                                AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                                alert11.show();
                            }
                        });

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    private void deleteSelectedItems() {
        SparseBooleanArray checked = gridView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        if (checked != null) {
            List<Object> list = mSelected;
            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                if (checked.get(i)) {
                    Object item = list.get(i);
                    mSelected.remove(item);
                    checked.delete(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**GridviewAdapter.java**

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model_images> {

    Context context;
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    int int_position;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu,int position) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, al_menu);
        this.al_menu = al_menu;
        this.context = context;
        this.int_position = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.size() + "");
        Log.e("ADAPTER LIST SIZE", al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size() + "");
        return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        if (al_menu.size() > 0) {
            return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size();
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, parent, false);
            viewHolder.tv_foldern = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder);
            viewHolder.tv_foldersize = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_folder2);
            viewHolder.iv_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tv_foldern.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.tv_foldersize.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        Glide.with(context).load("file://" + al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .into(viewHolder.iv_image);


        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv_foldern, tv_foldersize;
        ImageView iv_image;

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`?

Comment: `gridView.getCheckedItemPositions()` only return with Choice option . So if you are using Custom adapter  have a look into [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492280/android-gridview-multiple-selection).

Comment: I am able to select multiple items without using 'CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE' but I am not able to delete them all at once when I click delete button @ADM

Comment: Post code for GridViewAdapter also

Comment: done @SanjayMajoka

Comment: what is button1 button2 button3... please write as btnDelete, btnSave etc. and al_images is not defined in activity

Comment: full code is available at https://github.com/redviper00/game, everything is defined there @SanjayMajoka

Answer (score 2):

You can do like that

In Activity -

```
  public class PhotosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private ArrayList<Integer> mSelected = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
    gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                    if(mSelected.contains(position)) {
                        mSelected.remove(position);
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);// remove item from list
                        // update view (v) state here
                        // eg: remove highlight
                    }
                    else {
                        mSelected.add(position);
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);// add item to list
                        // update view (v) state here
                        // eg: add highlight
                  }
                  .....
                  .....
                  .....

  }
```

now call method of adapter as on delete btn click -

```
adapter.updateUpdapter(mSelecected);
```

In Adapter -

```
 public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu,int position) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_adapter__photos_folder, al_menu);
        this.al_menu.addAll(al_menu);
       ....
    }

private void updateUpdapter(ArrayList<Integer> mSelected){
        for(int selected: mSelected){
            al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().remove(selected);
        }
        notifiDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I hope it will help .

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you only remove one position from the adapter.

```
... 
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                deleteSelectedItems();
                                                al_images.remove(position);
                                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
...
```

I can't test the code at the moment,but try:

```
private void deleteSelectedItems() {
        SparseBooleanArray checked = gridView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        if (checked != null) {
            List<Object> list = mSelected;
            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                    mSelected.remove(checked.keyAt(i));
                    al_images.remove(checked.keyAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated `deleteSelectedItems()`  function ,so that it also deletes the checked position from the adapter. Before, you were deleting all the selected items from the list, but only one item (position) from the adapter.

Comment: I updated the code again, can you try if this one works?

Answer (score 0):

Select and delete multiple items :

1. The moment you select the item store the position or the unique value of that item in an array or list.
2. After selecting the item/s, when user presses the `Delete` button loop through your main items and remove the selected item from it.
3. Refresh the Adapter by calling `notifyDataSetChanged();`

   ```
   //based on item position
   List < Integer > selectedItems = new ArrayList < > ();

   public void onSelected(int pos) {
    selectedItems.add(pos);
   }

   public deleteItems() {
    for (Integer pos = selectedItems) {
     mainItems.remove((int)pos);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```

Comment: I am facing problem with step 2, somehow code isn't able to implement that