# In grid view selecting views present on screen but on scroll down i am unable to select it

Tags: android

In grid view selecting views present on screen but on scroll down I am unable to select it

I am using `gridview` and on item select I make the selected item background to green and on deselected transparent but if I scroll down to select more items it randomly select and deselect the items, please help to fix it.

```
 studentGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            desiredBackgroundColor = Color.rgb(0, 255, 0);
            try {

                Student student = (Student) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String stuName = student.getStudent_name();
                String stuId = student.getStudent_nid();

                view = studentGridView.getChildAt(position);

                ColorDrawable viewColor = (ColorDrawable) view.getBackground();
                clickCount++;

                if (viewColor == null) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(desiredBackgroundColor);
                    mainclickCount = clickCount;
                   //clickCount++;
                   //mainclickCount = clickCount;

                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "firstclick: " + clickCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("clickCounttt", "" + mainclickCount);
                    studentselList.add(stuName);
                    studentselnidList.add(stuId);
                    Log.d("viewColor", "" + viewColor);
                    Log.d("studentselListdee", studentselList.toString());

                    if (mainclickCount > 0) {
                        doneIv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        doneIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    String studentselListStr = studentselList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                    showstudentTv.setText(studentselListStr);
                    if (isStudentClick == true) {
                        showstudentTv.setText(studentselListStr);
                    } else if (isStaffClick == true) {
                        showstaffTv.setText(studentselListStr);
                    }
                    return;
                }

                int currentColorId = viewColor.getColor();
                Log.d("currentColorId", "" + currentColorId);

                if (currentColorId == desiredBackgroundColor) {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    clickCount--;
                    mainclickCount = clickCount;
                    studentselList.remove(stuName);
                    studentselnidList.remove(stuId);
                    String studentselListStr = studentselList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                    showstudentTv.setText(studentselListStr);
                    if (isStudentClick == true) {
                        showstudentTv.setText(studentselListStr);
                    } else if (isStaffClick == true) {
                        showstaffTv.setText(studentselListStr);
                    }

                } else {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(desiredBackgroundColor);
                    clickCount++;
                    mainclickCount = clickCount;
                    studentselList.add(stuName);
                    String studentselListStr = studentselList.toString().toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
                    showstudentTv.setText(studentselListStr);
                }

                Log.d("clickCountmainn", "" + mainclickCount);
                Log.d("studentselListtt", studentselList.toString());

                if (mainclickCount > 0) {
                    doneIv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    doneIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

**xml file**

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/studentGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
            android:scrollingCache="false"

            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/classselLayout"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/doneLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_150"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/done"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40"
                android:src="@drawable/done1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_40"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_40"
                android:src="@drawable/cross"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the state of item Views. Look at this 
http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/01/gridview-with-multiple-selection-in.html It can give you some idea.

This one can also helps you [Android GridView Multiple Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492280/android-gridview-multiple-selection)